# Converting '01' string to int prints only 1 why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, integer

```
a='0'
print(int(a)) # OUTPUT IS 0
b='01'
print(int(b)) # OUTPUT IS 1
c='00111'     
print(int(c)) # OUTPUT IS 111
```

When i convert string '0' to int and print it gives me 0 . But when i convert strings like '0111' or '01' to int it only prints all 1 but not 0 why? and how to get that 0 , i tried lots of things but it dosent work

I want that when i give input in string like '0011' and after converting this input in int it should give me output 0011

Comment: Integers do not have leading zeroes, which are non signifcant figures and which are not really there.

Comment: So if the integer is 111, why would python want to print this as 00111 and not 000000111? It seams clear that your original string representation does not matter anymore once the integer is just a number.

Comment: Can you please clarify why you expect a numerical value to include leading zeroes? Would you expect your hypothetical int to satisfy `int('001') == int('01')`? If you want to preserve the format, why don't you stick with strings?

Comment: Integers do not *have* digits at all. Digits (decimal or otherwise) are a *way of representing* the number. Expecting to control the number of leading zeros on an integer is kind of like expecting to be able to alter a photograph by doing surgery on the people in it.

Comment: Keep both values - i.e., use the input string for presentation (printing) and convert to int for arithmetic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a not entirely serious answer with a class which produces the output you were hoping for. This subclass of `int` counts the leading zeros in the string passed to the init method and stores it as an attribute. Then it uses it to generate the string representation.

Only for instructional purposes. Do not use.

The resulting objects can be added just like normal ints, however the result of additions, multiplications etc. are normal ints (no leading zeros). One would need to implement the `__add__` dunder method in order to produce `IntLeadingZeros` from addition. And then the question becomes, how many leading zeros should the sum have?

I repeat, do not use.

```
class IntLeadingZeros(int):
    def __new__(self, value):
        return int.__new__(self, value)
    
    def __init__(self, value):
        int.__init__(value)
        self.nzeros = len(value) - len(value.lstrip('0')) if len(value) > 1 else 0

    def __str__(self):
        len_str = len(str(int(self)))
        return f"{int(self):0{len_str + self.nzeros}d}"
        

a='0'
print(IntLeadingZeros(a)) # OUTPUT IS 0
b='01'
print(IntLeadingZeros(b)) # OUTPUT IS 01
c='00111'     
print(IntLeadingZeros(c)) # OUTPUT IS 00111
```

Answer (score 2):

Integers cannot have leading zeros. If desired, you can add zeros after the operation and convert it to a string.
For example

```
a = "003"
b = "008"
c = str(int(a) + int(b)).zfill(3)
print(c)
```

**Output**

```
011
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah, I mean if it's a string and you have to keep the leading zero after operation like sum

Answer (score 0):

Why? Because 0...01=1. That's basically why.
Why store an int as 01 if you can just store 1? If you want to have the zeroes in front, you would have to convert back to string and add them, because 0001 is not an int.